# Escaping meta chars in slides apps script not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

I want to match 212*235 as plain text in Slides service Text Range. Hence I used

var trs = text.find('212*234');
var trs = text.find(/212*234/);

also tried with

var re = new RegExp("212*234", "gi");
var trs = text.find(re);

but none of them worked.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-range#findpattern

Is this might be a bug or intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want two backslashes before the `*`, as in:

```
var s = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides()[0].getShapes()[0];
Logger.log(s.getText().find('212\\*235')[0].asString());
```

Comment: Is there a way to make case sensitive and case insensitive. Any documentation source for the find function parameters?

Comment: Sorry, dont believe there's a way to make it case insensitive. You can file a feature request [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#missing_features)